# Ruby: EventMachine not loading

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

UPDATE:

I found the simple answer and it's completely my own fault: I stored the above code in a file called "eventmachine.rb". Thus when I required 'eventmachine' it just imported the same file, which does not contain a definition for EventMachine.

So this is not really a post about EventMachine.

ORIGINAL POST:

Excuse me, but what's going on?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine'

EventMachine
```

gives

```
uninitialized constant EventMachine
```

in both TextMate and on the console when I run "ruby myfile.rb".

But if I type the same thing into IRB, I get

```
=> EventMachine
```

.

...

I got so frustrated that I followed the rash instructions on http://blog.carlmercier.com/2007/12/14/how-to-fix-that-rubygems-mess-on-leopard/ -- wiping out my Ruby and Rubygems environments and reinstalling them from MacPorts. IRB still works and TextMate/commandline still fails in the same way. I even reduced my TextMate PATH to the one place where Ruby, Gem, and IRB are installed now: /opt/local/bin -- which is what Which reports.

Finally, when I

```
puts Gem.path
```

on either IRB, TextMate, or the console, I get the same path.

Comment: A bit off topic: I strongly recommend using rvm for managing your rubies on Mac. https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/. That post you looked at is from 2007. Tools for ruby have circled the galaxy since then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the simple answer and it's completely my own fault:
I stored the above code in a file called "eventmachine.rb".  Thus when I required 'eventmachine' it just imported the same file, which does not contain a definition for EventMachine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the gem?

```
gem install eventmachine
```

Typically an error like that in the code you show is because the line

```
require 'eventmachine'
```

failed and that class/module constant, EventMachine, is not defined.

Also, if you are running ruby 1.9, you no longer need to have

```
require 'rubygems'
```

Comment: I did install the gem.  Sorry if I'm not understanding, but I thought any time you require a file that doesn't exist you get    "no such file to load".  So it looks like the gem is fine in that regard.

Comment: Ah. You are correct. Have you tried typing these lines into irb? What happens at each line? Same result? Does require 'eventmachine' return true?

Comment: Actually in IRB it returns true and EventMachine works.  It fails as described in TextMate and by running "ruby mycode.rb" at the commandline.

Comment: I got so frustrated I followed the rash instructions on http://blog.carlmercier.com/2007/12/14/how-to-fix-that-rubygems-mess-on-leopard/ wiping out my Ruby and Rubygems environments and reinstalling them from MacPorts.  IRB still works and TextMate/commandline still fails in the same way.  I even reduced my TextMate PATH to the one place where Ruby, Gem, and IRB are installed now: /opt/local/bin -- which is what Which reports.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why the message is "Uninitialized Constant", but the problem is that you provided nothing to run.    I get the same error with your code, but if I change it to:

```
EventMachine::run{
   EventMachine::add_periodic_timer( 0.1) { 
    print '.'
   }
}
```

then it works exactly as I expect - it prints 10 dots per second.

Comment: hm that gives me the same UninitializedConstant error.  As I said in my comments to rnichoson, I get this error in TextMate and running Ruby from the commandline, but in IRB, I can say require 'eventmachine'; EM; #gives "EventMachine".

Comment: another interesting fact: when I do "puts Gem.path" on either IRB, TextMate, or the console, I get the same path.